# Interruptible Socket Read Java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, stream, client-server

I'm trying to create a fairly simple client/server application in java. The client has two threads and the server has two threads (per client), one for input and output. I am sending data both ways pretty much constantly over Object Streams. Read() blocks. I need to be able to interrupt the read() thread (ie to disconnect). How do I do this?

Comment: think this [link](http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/shutting_down_threads_cleanly.shtml) can actually help you.

Comment: Have you try to use non-blocking read socket? Also to have a loop to constantly check for a condition so that when you need to disconnect you can disconnect after the non-blocking read return? You can use NIO or setSoTimeout to create a non-blocking socket.

Answer (score 2):

Shutdown the socket for input. This will cause the blocked read to throw `EOFException`, whereupon it should close the socket and exit the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Close the `Socket`, and the `read` method will be interrupted with a `IOException`. Handle that exception to clean up your thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use non blocking calls or use [Interrupt method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) on the thread. Once interrupted, the read operation will throw an Exception which you can catch and end the thread nicely.

Comment: That's only true if the socket is an InterruptibleChannel.